# Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: android, admob

My logcat is showing such error on adding admob to my project.I have tried manually adding sdk jar file but still doesn't work.My libs folder consist of jars-google-play-services and
  android-support-v4.i have referred to other posts with same error but nothing works for me.

logcat

```
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmlpullparserproject/com.example.xmlpullparserproject.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at com.example.xmlpullparserproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    ... 11 more
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
07-02 00:26:42.082: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    ... 21 more
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="xyz"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"

                         />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActvity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)       // 
        .addTestDevice("3a2d1115ab64e3") // 
         .build() ;
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Did any of the solutions given work?

Answer (score 2):

The ad xml namespace is wrong:

**In GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar or earlier you use:**

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
```

with the namespace:

```
 xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

**In Google admob via the play service library, you use:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

with the namespace:

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

Answer (score 1):

try cleaning and rebuilding the project. But the error is clear, it can't find the  class com.google.ads.AdView  which is in the google play sdk jar. If you've updated to tools api 17+ you will need to physically create a libs folder and drop that jar in that folder or setup your export path in the preferences.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="xyz"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"

                         />
```

i also noticed your adview call looks different than the new version:  (missing the .gms)

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```